# Automated test generator

Tags: c#, unit-tests, tdd, .net

After a long road with Randoop.NET as a unit test suggestion tool, my developing team has decided to upgrade to a commercial tool which will provide us a full unit testing framework for professional TDD workflow.

- super important for it to include a well-performing runner AND a mocking framework, the coverage part is less relevant but can be an advantage.
- must be super userfriendly and easy to manage but yet powerful and efficient.

P.S - 
We work on VS2017 with .net framework

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So you have decide to purchase a commercial tool, but you are asking us which one?

Comment: Poeerful in what sense? Efficient in what sense?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with fuzz testing is that it inefficiently tries input onto your target code, tries to be as smart as a human in test design.

If we are thinking about TDD (i.e. have a coverage which enables us to modify our software with a mitigated risk of regression), [mutation testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZjPzlX9YJY) is an appropriated techinique.

In the C# world, [Visual Mutator](https://visualmutator.github.io/web/) is highly recommended. [NinjaTurtlesMutation](https://github.com/criteo/NinjaTurtlesMutation) seems to be a good tool as well.